# Get the index in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to get the index of an instance in a has_many relationship. For example, `A` has many `B`s, and there is a `b`(`B`'s instance) which belongs to an `a`. If we sort all `b`s by their id, `b` will be Xth `B` in `a.bs`. I want to get the X.

Is it even possible without iterating over all `a.bs`? If I have to create a new column to store this index, how to avoid race condition?

**Edit**: The solution I figured out is:

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_extra_index

  def add_extra_index
     self.extra_index = self.a.bs.count
  end
end
```

But obviously there is a race condition.

Comment: `a.bs.map(&:id).index(b.id)` OR `a.bs.map(&:id).index(b.id)+1`

Comment: I believe it iterates over all `a.bs`. After all, this is how `map` works.